# Undefined reference to functions in CCGLViewImpl for Ubuntu in codeblocks

Tags: cocos2d-x, codeblocks

I am trying to build cocos2-dx based project in code blocks. I use Ubuntu 14. I got the following errors

> GAME_DIR/SampleGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLViewImpl-desktop.cpp:287:
>   undefined reference to `glfwSetErrorCallback'
>   GAME_DIR/SampleGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLViewImpl-desktop.cpp:348:
>   undefined reference to`glfwWindowHint'
>   GAME_DIR/SampleGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLViewImpl-desktop.cpp:360:
>   undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
>   GAME_DIR/SampleGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLViewImpl-desktop.cpp:361:
>   undefined reference to`glfwMakeContextCurrent'
>   GAME_DIR/SampleGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLViewImpl-desktop.cpp:364:
>   undefined reference to `glfwSetCursorPosCallback'
>   GAME_DIR/SampleGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLViewImpl-desktop.cpp:365:
>   undefined reference to`glfwSetScrollCallback'
>   GAME_DIR/SampleGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLViewImpl-desktop.cpp:368:
>   undefined reference to `glfwSetWindowPosCallback'
>   GAME_DIR/SampleGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLViewImpl-desktop.cpp:369:
>   undefined reference to`glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback'
>   GAME_DIR/SampleGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLViewImpl-desktop.cpp:371:
>   undefined reference to `glfwSetWindowIconifyCallback'

Answer (score 0):

I got answer for my own question.

I changed target platform to Unix, which previously set as all. Then I added my classes in cmake.txt. Then I clean it and Build. That worked.